# Single planning calendar with fullday off

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem with **Single planning calendar**.

I set **fullday** to false and set a startHour (8h) and endHour (17h).

But when i want to resize an appointment the startDate is not correct.

```
handleAppointmentResize: function (oEvent) {
    var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment"),
        oStartDate = oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
        oEndDate = oEvent.getParameter("endDate"),
        sAppointmentTitle = oAppointment.getTitle();
    
    console.log(oStartDate);
    console.log(oEndDate);
```

For exemple :

I have an appointment :

Wed Apr 06 2022 09:00:00 to Wed Apr 06 2022 13:00:00

I reduce them to 09:00 - 10:00

The result is

```
Mon Apr 04 2022 19:30:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
Wed Apr 06 2022 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
```

If i switch fullday to true, the result is ok !

Thanks for help

---

Resolve with upgrade of Sapui5 version

Comment: Do you still having this issue?

Comment: yes, with upgrade Sapui5 Version.